# Splitting clipboard import in ABAP

Tags: clipboard, abap

I'm using CLPB_IMPORT function module to get clipboard to internal table. it's ok. I'am copying two column Excel data. So it fills the table with delimiter '#', like;

> 1. 4448#3000
> 2. 4449#4000
> 3. 4441#5000

But the problem is splitting these strings. I'm trying;

```
LOOP AT foytab.
    SPLIT foytab-tab  AT '#' INTO temp1 temp2.
ENDLOOP.
```

But it doesn't split. it puts whole line into temp1. I think the delimiter is not what I thought ('#'). Because when I write a string manually with delimiter '#' it splits.

Do you have any idea how to split this ?

Comment: trying to get a SAP stack exchange started, check it out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `CLPB_IMPORT` since it's explicitly marked as obsolete. Use `CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>CLIPBOARD_IMPORT` instead.

The data is probably not separated by `#` but by a tab character. You can check this in the hex view of the debugger. `#` is just a replacement symbol the UI uses for any unprintable character. If the delimiter is the tab character, you can use the constant `CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>HORIZONTAL_TAB`.

[image]